# How to get all dependencies classes during maven build in maven plugin

Tags: java, maven

I'm creating maven plugin which should get list of classes from dependencies of pom where this plugin is defined and check if these classes have certain annotation. Is it possible to get all source classes from pom and interate over them to check existing of annotation?

Comment: You can output it in a text file during build. [More](http://pinkpawmovement.com/2023/01/25/how-to-get-all-dependencies-classes-during-maven-build-in-maven-plugin/)

Comment: You can get all the dependencies (as in a path to the jar file). After that is up to you to open those jars and read the class files. You shouldn't use reflection to load those classes as it will probably create clashes with the classes already loaded by maven, so you'll need to load the java bytecode as an AST and use that to find the annotations. You can check the code of the maven [dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/scm.html) to get some inspiration

Comment: First question for what exact purpose do you build your plugin? From the dependencies you can get the jar dependencies and trying to check those classes/jar having particular annotation... You have to set `requiresDependencyCollection = ResolutionScope.COMPILE` in your mojo ... and furthermore you need to get the deps via MavenSession/MavenProject (injected into your mojo)... it would be helpful to see your mojo code + pom what you have done so far?